# Compute: $\arcsin x+ \arctan \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\arcsin x+ \arctan \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$$
This problem is from my final test for this semester in the third year highschool. I think this should be solved by using Lagrange or Rolle.
I computed the derivative for $f(x)$ ,$f(x)$=$\arcsin x+ \arctan \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$ $f'(x)=0; $ Using Rolle we know that $f(a)=f(b) $ where $x\in(a,b)$

Comment: If you found that its derivative is zero, then the function must be locally constant. Since this function is continuous for $x>0$ and for $x<0$, you only need to evaluate it at some convenient $x>0$ and at some convenient $x<0$, to get what the constant(s) should be. For example, evaluating at $\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is simple.

Comment: And yes, like many problems in trigonometry (if not all) they can be solved using calculus. That starts from the very definition of the trigonometric functions.

Comment: Bet you could do it with power series, too. Using Lagrange multipliers seems tricky, but I’m sure there’s a way!

Comment: For the OP: Usually, we use Rolle when we want to prove that a function has a zero derivative on some interval. This function, you can compute to have a zero derivative everywhere in its domain without Rolle. Lagrange multipliers are used to find extreme values of a function subject to constraints. Since this problem doesn't ask you to minimize or maximize anything, there doesn't seem to be a very natural way to use that technique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a calculus problem at all; it's trigonometry. If you draw a right triangle, with one leg equal to $x$, and with the hypotenuse equal to $1$, then the other leg will have length $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Your first term represents the angle opposite the $x$ side, the your second term represents the angle adjacent to it. Those two angles add up to a right angle, i.e., $\pi\over 2$.

Of course, this analysis assumes that $x$ is the length of a triangle side, which is to say, that $x>0$. To take care of the other possibility, consider that $\arcsin$ and $\arctan$ are both *odd* functions.

Comment: Correction: Your solution might not be seen as calculus. The problem on the other hand doesn't satisfy that statement.

Comment: Ok Thanks for that.

Comment: Amazing! That's a very good observation, I wonder why our teacher decided to use this problem for our test

Comment: Being able to simplify this kind of trig expression is useful in calculus. Maybe that’s why. Or maybe, they expected you to use derivatives, and didn’t notice the easier approach.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs, What if $x<0?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, that's a fine question, to which I suspect you know the answer. :) Shall we leave it as an exercise for readers? Would it be too much of a spoiler to mention that the function is question is *odd*?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs, Thanks for the acknowledgement. Have u noticed my answer btw?

Comment: Yes, and it's a good one. Do you think I should edit mine, regarding the negative part of the domain? Probably so.....

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that by right triangle properties

$$\tan(\arcsin x)=\frac x {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arcsin x=y\implies x=\sin y,-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

$\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x=\arctan(\cot y)=\arctan\left(\left(\dfrac\pi2-y\right)\right)$

$=\begin{cases}\dfrac\pi2-y&\mbox{if } -\dfrac\pi2\le\dfrac\pi2-y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff\pi\ge y\ge0 \\\dfrac\pi2-y-\pi
 & \mbox{if } y\le0 \end{cases}$